# Run function when the scroll up is less then 275 from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the current fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/inkedraskal/8958g8hj/

with the current js:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            var isUp = (scroll < lastScrollTop);
            console.log(isUp);
            if (scroll >= 275) {
                $('body').addClass('moving-down');
                //$suvNavIcons.fadeOut();
            } else if(isUp is less then 275 from the top){
                $('body').removeClass('moving-down');
            }


            lastScrollTop = scroll;
        });
```

I can't do an else for the scroll because I am running another function that needs the body class, so I am only looking to remove the class if the "isUp" is less then 275 from the top.

Any one have any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8958g8hj/1/)?

Comment: @imgonzalves, I belive that will do it

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you intend but I think this is what you are looking for.

You only want the action to happen when scrolling up. And you only want the class removed at scroll positions greater than 275.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var isUp = scroll<lastScrollTop;
        console.log(isUp)
        if (isUp){
            if (scroll <= 275) {
                console.log('hi')
            $('body').addClass('moving-down');
            //$suvNavIcons.fadeOut();
            }else{
                $('body').removeClass('moving-down');
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = scroll;
    });
```

});